# Design a ZeroMQ program with a "middlend" interface

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

In advance, I'm sorry for that kind of question because I'm new to `ZeroMQ` and after reading cryptic `ZeroMQ` documentation and write some test cases, I'm stuck on designing my program.

My first version was using a `ROUTER` (as a frontend) and a `DEALER` (as a backend). See below :

```
[ clients N] --> [ Frontend ] --> [ Backend ] --> [ Workers N ]
```

That's simple and standard so the code works fine. Now, I got something new. After `clients N` sends a request pre-processing must be done on the `payload` before sending it to the `backend`. And you know what? I would like that pre-processing asynchronously.

My actual code uses a ROUTER-TO-DEALER design but now, should I design something like ROUTER-TO-ROUTER-TO-DEALER?

( I read in the documentation ROUTER-TO-ROUTER (N to N) is difficult to design ).

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouting *(cit.) "**Any ideas?**"* is definitely not a good habit at StackOverflow. Would you mind to **read about how to best ask the MCVE-based questions** ? StackOverflow encourages users to present a **M**inimum ( efficiency ) + **C**omplete ( self-contained ) + **V**erifiable ( ready for re-runs ) + **E**xamples ( a full example, with all details+data, to allow others to re-test ) of code, that you tried to make work and struggle to make it work right. The best next step is to learn about this Community practices + revise & complete your MCVE above. This great Community of Knowledge cares

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using something like the `rrbroker` from [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc39). In that case you could add an additional socket of type `DEALER` as middleend, to which pre-processing workers can connect. Routing within the broker would be:

- frontened -> middleend
- middleend -> backend
- backend -> frontend